# Google Play error 501 when updating YouTube

Tags: google-play-store, youtube

I'm trying to update the YouTube app. Whenever the update downloads and it shows "Updating app". It takes a lot of time and after some time, an error is displayed "Unknown error 501". I've searched for many solutions on Google. I've tried all the possible solutions but didn't worked. Anyone can help?

Comment: Please  [edit] to mention what are the things you tried. Else somebody may suggest something that you have already tried and it's a waste of effort for both.

Comment: @beeshyams a list of Playstore error codes can be found on our [google-play-store tag-wiki](/tags/google-play-store/info), linking to the relevant posts. But we don't yet have the 501 listed yet (this is the first Q for it). // **Saad:** Could you please verify if this tutorial helps you: https://appuals.com/google-play-store-error-501/ (I can't as I don't have the issue and do not use Playstore anyway). Alternative guide: https://www.unlockunit.com/blog/fix-google-play-store-error-501/ Please let us know if it (and what) did the trick. Good luck!

Comment: @beeshyams always check the tag wikis first :) We've often placed "core stuff" into them, so we can find it if needed. And I'd say we should continue doing so :)

Comment: Have you tried clearing Play Store cache and/or uninstalling Play Store updates? Worked for me. Posting as comment because I don't know if you've done this already

Comment: @user153812 yes i did. Didn't worked.

Comment: @Saad Khan- any success since then? Do post if you found a solution.

Comment: @user153812 Not yet